# How to make nginx not return the response body when performing redirection?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

An example configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

nginx returns a response body when performing a redirect.

```bash
$ curl -v http://www.example.com
*   Trying 121.5.221.184:80...
* Connected to www.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 16:13:04 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.example.com/
< 
{ [162 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think this response body is useful, and instead wastes server bandwidth. Is it possible to make nginx not return any response body when performing redirection?